# Getting error trying to make Terraform work with IBM Cloud

Tags: terraform, ibm-cloud, terraform-provider-ibm

I am using the following instructions:
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/terraform/setup_cli.html#setup_cli

When I run `terraform init`

I get the following error:
Provider "ibm" not available for installation.

```
A provider named "ibm" could not be found in the official repository.

This may result from mistyping the provider name, or the given provider may
be a third-party provider that cannot be installed automatically.

In the latter case, the plugin must be installed manually by locating and
downloading a suitable distribution package and placing the plugin's executable
file in the following directory:
    terraform.d/plugins/windows_amd64

Terraform detects necessary plugins by inspecting the configuration and state.
To view the provider versions requested by each module, run
"terraform providers".
```

I am on windows 10 pc, I tried placing following executable under:

```
$HOME/terraform.d/plugins/windows_amd64/terraform-provider-ibm_v0.14.1.exe
```

Can anyone point why this is not working?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bug in instructions of IBM Cloud. But when I put the executable file under the following path it works:

```
$HOME\terraform.d\plugins\terraform-provider-ibm_v0.14.1.exe
```

Hope this answer will help save someone some time.

Answer (score 0):

There are clear steps on how to configure the IBM Cloud Provider for Terraform in this **[solution tutorial](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/tutorials/infrastructure-as-code-terraform.html#setup)** on both Windows and non-windows operating systems.

On Windows, the file needs to be placed in terraform.d/plugins beneath your user's "Application Data" directory.

Run the below commands on a command prompt [Provider Configuration](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html)

```
MD %USERPROFILE%\AppData\terraform.d\plugins
MOVE PATH_TO_UNZIPPED_PROVIDER_FILE\terraform-provider-ibm.exe  %USERPROFILE%\AppData\terraform.d\plugins
```

Launch Windows Powershell (Start + R > Powershell) and run the below command to create terraform.rc file

```
echo > $env:APPDATA\terraform.rc
```

At the first prompt, enter the below content

```
# ~/.terraformrc
providers {
   ibm = "PATH_TO_YOUR_APPDATA_PLUGINS/terraform-provider-ibm.exe"
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to store this ibm plugin on one remote server and make a call to access it through that instead of loading it on our local each time?

Answer (score 0):

The file `terraform.rc` should be saved with Encoding ANSI and you have to be sure of not having weird characters.

[image: file saving]